# how to restore reference of your object in java. In code below i have assigned c1 to c2. How can restore the object having (50, 30) values back to c2

Tags: java

how to restore reference of your object in java. In code below i have 
assigned c1 to c2. How can restore the object having  (50, 30) values back to c2

```
public class MyClass
{
public int a;
public int b;

public MyClass(int first, int second) // constructor
{
    this.a = first;
    this.b = second;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    MyClass c1 = new MyClass(10, 20); // creating objects
    MyClass c2 = new MyClass(50, 30);

    c2 = c1;
    System.out.println(c2.a); // printing variable a of c2
}
}
```

Output :
10
How to restore reference of object (50, 30) to c2.

Comment: you are changing the ref of MyClass c2 ... there is no way to go back....

Comment: instead of using the = operator consider implementing a MEMENTO pattern,

Comment: once you have thrown that envelope in the post office mail box, there is no way you are getting it back.  It's gone.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `c2 = c1;`, both `c1` and `c2` are referring to `new MyClass(10, 20);` object.

And `new MyClass(50, 30);` is still is memory(`RAM`) but there is no reference to it (it's moving freely in space).

Now you cannot get it back because it has been lost in space.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get back your old value. In fact when you assigned c1 to c2 you just threw the old reference away and set a new one to c1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing: `c2 = c1;` which is actually changing the reference of c2 improve the class a little bit so you can store/restore the last value, a LIFO structure can be implemented using a Java Stack class.

## Example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private Stack<MyClass> myx;

    public MyClass(int first, int second) {
        a = first;
        b = second;
        myx = new Stack<>();
        myx.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "a=" + myx.peek().a + ", b=" + myx.peek().b;
    }

    public static void move(MyClass l, MyClass r) {
        l.myx.push(r);
    }

    private void restore() {
        if (myx.size() > 1) {
            myx.pop();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass c1 = new MyClass(10, 20);
        MyClass c2 = new MyClass(-50, -30);
        MyClass c3 = new MyClass(-77, -77);
        MyClass.move(c2, c1);
        MyClass.move(c2, c3);
        System.out.println("c2: " + c2.toString());
        c2.restore();
        System.out.println("c2: " + c2.toString());
        c2.restore();
        c2.restore();
        c2.restore();
        System.out.println("c2: " + c2.toString());
    }

}
```